# Select $n$ items out of $N$ with replacement

Tags: probability

Select a subset of $n$ items out of $N$ with replacement and repeat $r$ times. 
(This can be done in ${N \choose n}^r$ ways, right?)

What is the probability that $k$ elements are contained in each subset selected?
So we have chosen $r$ subsets of $n$ elements. If we want $k$ fixed then we get $$\frac{{N-k \choose n-k}^r}{{N \choose n}^r}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. No, it should also be multiplied by $k!$, since you can have a permutation of this subset.

Comment: Oh that is true. Thank you very much!

Comment: do you have time to chat because I have another question for this one

Comment: in a few hours maybe

Comment: until then could you help me more with the other question please

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/81944/probability?tab=general please enter here if you want to ask more questions.